# Internet connection issues when lease expires

Tags: windows, networking, ip

***Except for Google/G+/Youtube & sites like stackexchange.com and so on and a few websites were connecting to the Internet, and rest it didn't***

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Acer>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : C7-8C-KC-1F-AY-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.127(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : 13 November 2018 10:04:20
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : 14 November 2018 14:57:56
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.251
                                       192.168.0.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

In the command prompt

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
ipconfig /flushdns

netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled

netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
```

---

**Didn't Fix!**

```
C:\Users\Acer>ipconfig /release

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{465C6A00-FEDB-40C7-A11B-61F695C452F0}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

C:\Users\Acer>ipconfig /renew

Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.127
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

C:\Users\Acer>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.

C:\Users\Acer>netsh winsock reset catalog

Sucessfully reset the Winsock Catalog.
You must restart the computer in order to complete the reset.


C:\Users\Acer>netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
Reseting Global, OK!
Reseting Interface, OK!
Reseting Unicast Address, OK!
Reseting Route, OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.


C:\Users\Acer>netsh int tcp set heuristics disabled
Ok.


C:\Users\Acer>netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled
Ok.


C:\Users\Acer>netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled
Ok.
```

**What is the actual reason behind this?**

Comment: Possibly DNS errors. Why do you have 192.168.1.251 and 192.168.0.1 for the DNS? The second one is enough.

Comment: What does it means with having such DNS?. How should I need to solve this. Since Internet fluctuates for a few seconds and comes to normal behavior @harrymc

Comment: This is probably the normal time it takes for DNS to be published in your network. I don't know what is 192.168.1.251, but it may not be necessary.